# Unity : How to handle compound colliders 2D physics

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, rigid-bodies

I´m making a small game where the basic game mechanic is dragging things around the level . My Player G.O. is the one who drags the other objects around the level . This G.O. (the player GO) has a rigidBody2D component , and in order to drag other objects , I turn the dragged object into a child of the player , so that I only move the player through the rigidBody component and the dragged object moves along the player object .

The problem is that whenever something that should kill the player by contact makes contact with the object that is being dragged , the death of the player still triggers even though the player has not make contact with the hazardous object to begin with . This is obviously not the intended result , if something that is meant to kill the player makes contact with the dragged object but not the player , the player should not be killed . How can I fix this?

EDIT : By killing I mean destroying the player GO.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete your parent GameObject, all its child GameObjects will delete with it too. In order to not get your dragged objects deleted, you should remove them somewhere else before deleting the parent GameObject. You could do that by:
`YourChildGameObject.transform.SetParent(OtherParentGameObject, false);`

Also, [this link could help you](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/205391/how-to-get-list-of-child-game-objects.html).

Comment: Im sorry , The problem is that whenever something that should kill the player collides with the object that is being dragged , the player gets killed , I´m trying to prevent that

Comment: What do you mean by killing? Deleting it completely from hierarchy? A bit hard to understand what you are asking for.

Comment: He's talking about losing the game!

Comment: Yes , when the hazardous object makes contact with the player , the player G.O. gets deleted from scene.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with collisions.
Set different layers to player and enemies.
Go to Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics. On the bottom, you'll see a list of collisions. You can check which layers collide with which layers there. Set the "enemy" layer to collide only with the "player" layer.

Another way to do this is by checking what is the enemy colliding with OnCollisionEnter or OnTriggerEnter (depending on how you're doing it). You can do it like this:

```
//You can change this to OnTriggerEnter and "Collision" with "Collider"
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) 
{
    if (col.gameObject.name == "player")
    {
      //Kill the player
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Actualy , I do that
`void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
  {
   if(other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
   {
    other.gameObject.transform.DetachChildren();
    Destroy(other.gameObject);
   }
  }
`


Unfortunately , I can't limit the enemy layer to just colide with the player layer because the enemies need to collide the other layers too.

Comment: For the moment , my "kill" is just a simple Destroy(playerObject) . The thing is that this gets triggered when some hazardous object (object that has the script I have detailed above) makes contact with the dragged object , the "kill" triggers and the player G.O. gets destroyed.

Comment: Weird. Try adding a Debug.Log that prints the tag of the object that's being hit. Also, check the _hazardous objects_ don't change their tag when changing it's parents. 
We're going to solve this.

Comment: Sorry for answering so late . For some strange  reason the Debug.Log shows that the enemy is colliding with  the box even though there is no collision at all . When the Enemy collides with a box being dragged by a player , the Debug.Log shows that a collission has been detected with the player.